# Unable to generate XML file with this big URL

Tags: php, xml

I want to generate XML with this following code but it's giving error as I include big URL. Even cdata is not working:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; ++$i) {
    $track = $xml->addChild('track');
    $track->addChild('path', "data[");
    $track->addChild('title', "<![CDATA[http://r8---sn-5hn7sn7k.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mt=1417417897&mv=m&ms=au&ip=2001:1af8:4700:a022:1::4ae9&itag=18&initcwndbps=4948750&mm=31&sver=3&id=o-AB1_DFOem6qVMtWki7uWj0CcIevyqEaY_OtwcbRPKZXT&ipbits=0&upn=IFgTkloUxQQ&expire=1417439567&fexp=902522,907259,922247,927622,932404,935694,941004,942810,943909,947209,948124,952302,952605,952901,953912,957103,957105,957201&key=yt5&sparams=dur,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,mm,ms,mv,source,upn,expire&source=youtube&signature=7266EE8B52AAB9E3C6DECBADDD112BDF00E85EFB.362737C47ECAE4D9E25E900E8C24483799B2A8F8&dur=1554.831&title=8+Stunning+Linguistic+Miracles+of+The+Holy+Quran+%7C+Kinetic+Typography]]>");
}

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```

Comment: xml is a reserved name, use a different name for your element

Comment: Only for namespace prefixes/aliases. It is allowed as a node name.

Comment: Hi OP, did the below answer help you? You do not seem to have replied to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add CDATA sections with SimpleXML, only standard text nodes. But even that has a bug. The text can not contain entities (the `&...;`). The same bug exists in `DOMDocument::createElement` and `DOMNode::$nodeValue`. You can create the document with DOM however.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('xml'));

for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; ++$i) {
    $track = $root->appendChild($dom->createElement('track'));
    $track
      ->appendChild($dom->createElement('path'))
      ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('data['));
    $track
      ->appendChild($dom->createElement('title'))
      ->appendChild($dom->createCDATASection("http://r8---sn-5hn7sn7k.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mt=1417417897&mv=m&ms=au&ip=2001:1af8:4700:a022:1::4ae9&itag=18&initcwndbps=4948750&mm=31&sver=3&id=o-AB1_DFOem6qVMtWki7uWj0CcIevyqEaY_OtwcbRPKZXT&ipbits=0&upn=IFgTkloUxQQ&expire=1417439567&fexp=902522,907259,922247,927622,932404,935694,941004,942810,943909,947209,948124,952302,952605,952901,953912,957103,957105,957201&key=yt5&sparams=dur,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,mm,ms,mv,source,upn,expire&source=youtube&signature=7266EE8B52AAB9E3C6DECBADDD112BDF00E85EFB.362737C47ECAE4D9E25E900E8C24483799B2A8F8&dur=1554.831&title=8+Stunning+Linguistic+Miracles+of+The+Holy+Quran+%7C+Kinetic+Typography"));
}

$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
print($dom->saveXML());
```

You can see that DOM document has a bunch of methods to create the different node types. The nodes have some methods to append the new node to them.

The methods return the nodes so you can nest them.