# Add database information to text in Php

Tags: php, xml, database

I'm looking for a way to get the id row from my database inside a url

This is the code:

```
//Select the Database
mysql_select_db("vandermeulen",$db);
$result = mysql_query("select * from meul_rem_houses", $db);
//Create SimpleXMLElement object
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<funda-aanbod versie="1.0"/>');
//Add each column value a node of the XML object
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $mydata = $xml->addChild('wonen-object');
$mydata->addAttribute('ObjectID',$row['id']);
$mydata->addChild('kantoornaam',"Van der Meulen Makelaardij o.g.");
$mydata->addChild('aanbiedingstekst',$row['description']);
$mydata->addChild('aantal-kamers',$row['rooms']);
$mydata->addChild('postcode',$row['hzipcode']);
$mydata->addChild('huisnummer',$row['houseid']);
$mydata->addChild('straatnaam',$row['hlocation']);
$mydata->addChild('plaatsnaam',$row['hcity']);
$mydata->addChild('koophuur',$row['listing-type']);
$mydata->addChild('koopconditie',$row['listing-statur']);
$mydata->addChild('koopprijs',$row['price']);
$mydata->addChild('url',"http://vandermeu1.server154.nognietactief.nl/index.php?option=com_realestatemanager&task=view&id=.$row['id'].&catid=53&Itemid=299");
$mydata->addChild('bouwjaar',$row['year']);
$mydata->addChild('woonoppervlakte',$row['house_size']);
$mydata->addChild('soort-object',$row['property_type']);
}
mysql_close($db);
//Create the XML file
$fp = fopen("funda2.1.xml","wb");
//Write the XML nodes
fwrite($fp,$xml->asXML());
//Close the database connection
fclose($fp);
```

But it was not in the xml output

XML output:

```
<koopprijs>127500</koopprijs>
<url/>
<bouwjaar>0</bouwjaar>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: I have posted more @Kristiyan

Comment: Thanks, I've just answered you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to generate XML file with this big URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223475/unable-to-generate-xml-file-with-this-big-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated

```
<?PHP 

$url = htmlentities("http://vandermeu1.server154.nognietactief.nl/index.php?option=com_realestatemanager&task=view&id=".$row['uid']."&catid=53&Itemid=299");
$mydata->addChild('url',$url);

?>
```

Comment: The child still remains empty! Displays: <url/>

Comment: You have value in $row['id']?

Comment: Yeah, it also is used in object id and works there and gives the database value @vishal shah

Answer (score 0):

Change  `$row['id']` to `".$row['id']."`

**Edited:**

In this case try with CDATA:

```
$string = htmlspecialchars("<![CDATA[http://vandermeu1.server154.nognietactief.nl/index.php?option=com_realestatemanager&task=view&id=".$row['id']."&catid=53&Itemid=299]]>");

$mydata->addChild('url',$string)`
```

It is because you have URL address with "&". I didn't see it last time. 
You can read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: Hi Thanks, But this the same as vishal shas aswerd, but i got a empty output

Comment: @JoranDob, in your case you have problem with URL address. I've edited my answer with CDATA information.

Comment: Here is the php warning while running the script:Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild(): unterminated entity reference task=view&amp;id=1100&amp;catid=53&amp;Itemid=299]]&gt; in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/funda2.php on line 26

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response @Kristiyan