# Replace value in XML feed with php xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I (conceptually) understand which steps i have to take, but i can't translate it to a working code.

I have a XML feed with a structure like this:

```
<item id="1">
    <properties>
        <property name="region">
            <value>Cote d'azur</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</item>
<item id="2">
    <properties>
        <property name="region">
            <value>Côte d'Azur</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</item>
```

What i need is the feed to use consequent names, so i have to loop through each property with the `name` attribute and replace the value, but how?

So far i'm here, but this doesn't work

```
$xml_src = 'feed.xml';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($xml_src);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$regions = $xpath->evaluate('//property[@name = "region"]');
foreach($regions as $region){
    $newregion = $document->createElement('value', str_replace("Cote d'azur","Côte d'Azur",$region->nodeValue));
    $region->parentNode->replaceChild($newregion, $region);
}
echo $document->saveXml();
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::createElement(): unterminated entity reference YllÃ¤s in .. on line 17
Line 17:
$newregion = $document->createElement('value', str_replace("Cote d'azur","Côte d'Azur",$region->nodeValue));
```

To make it even more complicated, i sometimes have three `value` elements in each `property` with the name `city`. In that case i need to select the third element.

I hope anybody can help me out

Comment: Could you give a bit more details about "doesn't work" Do you get an error (if so what is the exact error message)? Or do you get a result that's not what you want (if so, what is the wanted result, and what is the actual)?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy the error message. I've added it to the question

Comment: Aha, I might be wrong, but I think you need to pass the value for your new element through `htmlspecialchars()`; for some reason, various of the XML functions in PHP expect you to pass valid XML fragments rather than text content.

Comment: I'm no PHP expert, but I am sharp with XPath. It looks like your `$regions` variable corresponds to the `<property>` tag, when it should in fact correspond to the `<value>` tag within the `<property>` tag

Comment: It doesn't have to do anything with `htmlspecialchars()`, tried that but still errors. I understand, @lambo477, what you mean, but i can't find out how to select the value element, To make it even more complicated, i sometimes have three `value` elements in each property with the name city. In that case i need to select the third element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is from a bug in PHP. Do not use the second argument for `DOMDocument::createElement()`. Create and append a text node to make sure that special characters are escaped into entities.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27225157/2265374

Anything in a DOM is a node. Not only the element, but attribute and texts, too. You can work on the [text nodes](http://www.php.net/domtext) inside the `value` elements directly:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//property[@name = "region"]/value/text()') as $text) {
  $text->data = str_replace("Cote d'azur","Côte d'Azur", $text->data);
}

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$regions = $xpath->query('//property[@name = "region"]/value');
foreach($regions as $region){
    $region->nodeValue = str_replace("Cote d'azur","Côte d'Azur",$region->nodeValue);
}
echo $document->saveXml();
```